# Open a new Terminal window in "ssh directory" (Mac OS Yosemite)

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, terminal

One can open a new Terminal window in a specific directory by doing

```
open -a Terminal /path/to/folder
```

**How can I open a new Terminal window in a "ssh directory"?** I tried something like

```
open -a Terminal ssh username@ipp.ip.ip.ip/path/to/folder
```

but of course it throws an error.

Comment: Given that you'd already be typing the `ssh` command, why would you not just type Command-N before it. It's actually easier than typing `open -a Terminal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script file e.g runssh.sh containing your command, that is

```
ssh username@ipp.ip.ip.ip/path/to/folder
```

Then run

```
open -a Terminal runssh.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reason, however it doesn't work for me. I don't get any error message, but nothing happen! I tried to get rid of the `path/to/folder` to really make sure I don't make a path-related mistake but still nothing happen. Do you have a clue?

Comment: Also, for ease, isn't there any way to do it without using an extern file?

Comment: I have MacOS 10.10 and it works just fine... Make sure you have runssh.sh in the current directory, or specify full path to it, that is `open -a Terminal /path/to/script/runssh.sh`

Comment: Also you can add some `echo` commands in the script to see if the output is displayed

Comment: No, nothing get echoed! But my path is correct, I've tried from beingg in the actual directory anyway. I can open `runssh.sh` by doing `open runssh.sh` but the command `open -a Terminal runssh.sh` has still no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a new Terminal window and execute an arbitrary command this way:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "echo This is a command"'
```

That said, I find no evidence that `ssh username@ipp.ip.ip.ip/path/to/folder` is a sensible command. Why do you expect that to work? Does it work if you just type it directly into an existing Terminal window? It doesn't for me. (Of course, I'm using a real host address and path.) It works if I leave off the path.